# OData using ICollection<ITax> convert to strong type

Tags: c#, odata

I'm using OData to make a post, but I need to pass a strongly typed object,
in my main class, I have this property that contains a collection of interfaces

```
public ICollection<ITax> Taxes { get; set; }
```

Each interface is implemented by a tax type, as we can see here.

```
    public sealed class Tax1 : ITax
    {
        public decimal BaseTotalAmount { get; set; }

        public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Tax2 : ITax
    {
        public decimal BaseTotalAmount { get; set; }

        public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
    }
```

The problem I'm not getting through via JSON that makes the identification of each type of tax.

```
"Taxes": [
        {
            "BaseTotalAmount": 1.0,
            "TotalAmount": 1.0
        }
    ]
```

how can I set a field that identifies me that the object is of type Tax1 in json?

Comment: There is no obvious way to do what you want here. You can augment the interface to include some additional defining characteristic, or you can have multiple `public ICollection<Tax1> Tax1Taxes { get; set; }`, `public ICollection<Tax2> Tax2Taxes { get; set; }` properties. If you can explain a bit more about what you are trying to do, we may be able to help. But, the key feature of interfaces is the limited contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy approach, that might not help you, but as you didn't deliver much of a context it is what I can give you.

You just need one `Tax` class and in addition one `enum`. Let's say `TaxType`.

```
public ICollection<Tax> Taxes { get; set; }

public enum TaxType
{
    TaxType1 = 0,
    TaxType2 = 1
}

public sealed class Tax : ITax
{
    public TaxType Type { get; set; }

    public decimal BaseTotalAmount { get; set; }

    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
}
```

Hope it helps